# How to control flow of a transactional stream with Spring Data R2DBC?

Tags: r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

Support for transactional streams seems to have been [recently implemented](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring) but due to its newness, there are not many code examples.

Could someone show an example of a transactional stream that does a series of database inserts and then returns some value on success, but with a midstream checkpoint in between inserts that tests some condition and might roll back the transaction and return different values depending on the checkpoint result?

Comment: Do you mean savepoint with `checkpoint`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware there is a `checkpoint` entity. I only meant checkpoint in the generic sense of some test occurring midstream that might direct the transaction to be cancelled and the stream to return some alternate result.

Comment: Although your comment makes me curious also to see an example of a savepoint which commits part of a transaction based on some midstream condition, with the ability to either rollback the entire transaction on some downstream condition or rollback only up to the savepoint on some other condition.

Answer (score 7):

Reactive transactions follow the same pattern as imperative ones:

1. A transaction is started before running any user-space commands
2. Run user-space commands
3. Commit (or rollback)

A few aspects to note here: A connection is always associated with a materialization of a reactive sequence. What we know from a `Thread`-bound connection that is bound to an execution in imperative programming translates to an materialization in reactive programming.

So each (concurrent) execution gets a connection assigned.

Spring Data R2DBC has no support for savepoints. Take a look at the following code example that illustrates a decision to either commit or rollback:

```
DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.create(connectionFactory);

TransactionalOperator transactionalOperator = TransactionalOperator
        .create(new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory));

transactionalOperator.execute(tx -> {

    Mono<Void> insert = databaseClient.execute("INSERT INTO legoset VALUES(…)")
            .then();

    Mono<Long> select = databaseClient.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM legoset")
            .as(Long.class)
            .fetch()
            .first();

    return insert.then(select.handle((count, sink) -> {

        if(count > 10) {
            tx.setRollbackOnly();
        }

    }));
}).as(StepVerifier::create).verifyComplete();
```

Notable aspects here are:

1. We're using `TransactionalOperator` instead of `@Transactional`.
2. The code in `.handle()` calls `setRollbackOnly()` to roll back the transaction.

Using `@Transactional`, you would typically use exceptions to signal a rollback condition.

Comment: Thanks, this makes R2dbc finally appealing.